Application with Eureka is not deregistered
Please help me figure out the problem. I have a Java EE application that is deployed in a kubernetes cluster on Wildfly 18.0.1. Eureka is also deployed in this cluster. I use this Maven dependency in my Java application:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.netflix.eureka</groupId>
    <artifactId>eureka-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.14</version>
</dependency>

This is the class that is responsible for registering and de-registering an application instance in Eureka:
@WebListener
public class ServerStartup implements javax.servlet.ServletContextListener{
    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        EurekaClientService.getInstance().deRegister();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        EurekaClientService.getInstance().registerInstance();
    }
}

deRegister method in EurekaClientService:
public void deRegister() {

    applicationInfoManager.setInstanceStatus(InstanceInfo.InstanceStatus.DOWN);
        sendHeartBeat();
        if(eurekaClient != null){
            eurekaClient.shutdown();
        }
        else{
            log.warn("eurekaClient is NULL, can't deRegister()");
        }

    }

    public void sendHeartBeat(){
        applicationInfoManager.refreshLeaseInfoIfRequired();
    }

applicationInfoManager - com.netflix.appinfo.ApplicationInfoManager
eurekaClient - com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient

The problem is that after the application is completed, it is not automatically unregistered from Eureka and, accordingly, Eureka remembers about it for some more time, which is incorrect behavior for me
I think it may be due to the library itself being used, that it cannot work with Java EE.
